# Difference between random.randint and random.sample

Tags: random

I have read the documentation for each and find it a bit hard to comprehend the differences here. I wrote this code using random.sample:

```
import random

print "Welcome to the guessing game."

number_of_guesses = 1
correct_number = random.sample(range(1,101),1)

while number_of_guesses < 999:

    user_choice = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))

    if user_choice == correct_number:
        print "You guessed the number in %s tries." % number_of_guesses

    elif user_choice < correct_number:
        print "Too low, guess again."
        number_of_guesses += 1

    elif user_choice > correct_number:
        print "Too high, guess again."
        number_of_guesses += 1
```

When i run this code and enter a number i get "Too low, guess again." regardless of what number I enter, yet when i use random.randomint it works correctly.  Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Both produce a random integer, and I'm attempting to understand why one allows my code to run correctly and the other doesn't.

Comment: random.sample returns a list of integers and random.randint returns an int.  Even though the list is a length of one you still need to get the first element.

Answer (score 3):

`random.sample(range(1,101),1)` will return a singleton list containing an integer, whereas `random.randint(1,100)` will directly return the integer itself. Note that `random.randint` is an inclusive bound (i.e. it can return either of the endpoints)

You could also use `random.choice(range(1, 101))` to get the integer. In any case, I'd assume that `randint` is the fastest option.